# Memory alignment syntax in C++

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

What determines C/C++ Memory Alignment Syntax?

I am working on some embedded application, which requires memory/data alignment. 
From my previous experience, for C code, with GCC and MSVC, the memory alignment syntax seems to be mainly determined by the compiler:

```
GCC   __attribute__ ((aligned (128)))
MSVC   __declspec(align(128))
```

I am curious about the following questions:

1. Does the alignment syntax also depend on other factors, such as
   target hardware and/or data model of OS? Or is it solely dependent
   on the compiler?
2. For C++11, is the new syntax `alignas(128)` part of the C++11
   standard and thus independent of compiler/platform?
3. For C++11, when we use `std::align` on data, will it do a full data
   copy and thus hinder the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The syntax doesn't change depending on what the target is.
2. Yes, [alignas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas)
   is a C++ keyword since C++11, but note:

   > If the strictest (largest) alignas on a declaration is weaker than the
   >   alignment it would have without any `alignas` specifiers (that is,
   >   weaker than its natural alignment or weaker than `alignas` on another
   >   declaration of the same object or type), the program is ill-formed

   Since types have different alignments on different platforms, this may work for one target platform and fail for another:

   ```
   struct alignas(2) foo { int bar; };
   ```
3. No, [std::align](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) does not copy data. It modifies a pointer and a `size_t` space counter if needed.

   > If the buffer is too small, the function does nothing and returns `nullptr`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still curious about "ill-formed" program in (2), does it mean it will be ignored, or does it mean undefined behavior?

Comment: @knightyangpku If I read [dcl.align](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.align#5) correctly, it should result in an error, but `g++` just ignores it and bumps up the alignment if needed. `clang++` rejects it as a hard error: "_error: requested alignment is less than minimum alignment of <number> for type <type>_"